# HTML onload - using variables as parameters

Tags: javascript, html, variables, parameter-passing, onload

I want to use something like:

```
<body onLoad="init('A sentence with "quoted text" as parameter')">
```

Unfortunately, this does work, as the quotes in the parameter are not treated properly.

Escaping the quotes also does not work

```
<body onLoad="init('A sentence with \"quoted text\" as parameter')">
```

(Above also does not work).

How do I deal with this. I though maybe I can create a string variable and assigne my sentence (with quotes) to it.  But I dont know how to do it! The body onload is HTML and the Javascript variables would be visible only within the scope of the script, right? To be precise, the following does not work:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var dada='A sentence with \"quoted text\" as parameter';
</script>
<body onLoad="init($dada, '</a>')">
```

Comment: The `language` attribute is deprecated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would have to use HTML entities to make it work:

```
<body onLoad="init('A sentence with &quot;quoted text&quot; as parameter')">
```

the much cleaner way, though, would be to assign the value in a separate `<SCRIPT>` part in the document's head.

```
...
<script>
body.onload = function() { init('A sentence with "quoted text" as parameter'); }
</script>
<body>
...
```

the `onload` event has the general downside that it is fired only when the document *and all its assets* (images, style sheets...) have been loaded. This is where the onDOMLoad event comes in: It fires when the core HTML structure is ready, and all elements are rendered. It is not uniformly supported across browsers, though, so all frameworks have their own implementation of it.

The jQuery version is called [`.ready()`.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thanks much. Am a beginner in javascript so missed such alternative styles.

Comment: @JP19 I had an error in the second block. If you use the code, make sure you copy over the change (The additional `function() { }`). Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than inlining the `onLoad` method, why not set it programatically. You can then use the power of [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) to get the data into the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = "some data";
document.body.onload = function()
{
    alert(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this looks good. Amd glad my question got solved so quickly.

Comment: Thanks.  This approach allowed me to fix the call to our IFrame resize  onload-handler (with passes a parameter / argument ), which broke when we moved from CRM2011 to CRM365/2016: var frameHandle = parent.document.getElementById("IFRAME_my Iframe"); // Was: frameHandle.setAttribute("onload", "myFrameResize(this);");
 frameHandle.onload = function () { myFrameResize(frameHandle); };

Answer (score 2):

not the nicest way

```
onload='init("A sentence with \"quoted text\" as parameter")'
```

Comment: This doesnt work, as I mentioned in the question. Thanks though!

Comment: oh. thanks.. yes, sorry I missed the different placement of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I was making a silly mistake.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var dada='A sentence with \"quoted text\" as parameter'; </script> 
<body onLoad="init(dada, '</a>')">
```

This works too. I was using $dada instead of dada in the onload call.