# Unterminated string constant JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Unterminated string constant

hello
I have a php code which is:

```
$bodier .= "setInterval('updateClock(\"$date2\",\"clock$x\")',1000);";
```

I use it like this:

```
<body onLoad="<?php echo trim($bodier) ; ?>">
```

it produces:

```
<body onLoad="setInterval('updateClock("2012-10-31 13:14:01","clock0")',1000);
setInterval('updateClock("2012-08-30 13:10:31","clock1")',1000);
setInterval('updateClock("2012-08-30 10:16:46","clock2")',1000);
setInterval('updateClock("2012-08-30 10:17:28","clock3")',1000);
setInterval('updateClock("2012-09-07 10:17:47","clock4")',1000);
setInterval('updateClock("2012-08-30 10:18:27","clock5")',1000);
setInterval('updateClock("2012-08-29 10:18:41","clock6")',1000);">
```

and it products an error:
Unterminates string constant

What am I doing wrong

I have also tried copying psting simpley the output as hardcoded instead of the php echo part

Answer (score 1):

You are doing common mistake here by putting unescapped quotation chars in the content string. See this example:

`"foo"bar"com"`

You may say that the string is `foo"bar"com` in fact it is `foo` as the next `"` closes the whole string. Same with your code. HTML parser sees: `"setInterval('updateClock("` as your onLoad script. Which is wrong.

EDIT: Some characters needs special escaping for HTML and these are called `entities`. So whatever you output to be used with HTML, you may want to always pass it through `htmlspecialchars()` function, to stay on safe ground

Answer (score 1):

valid html syntax is

```
<body onLoad="setInterval('updateClock(\"2012-10-31 13:14:01\",\"clock0\")',1000);">
```

you see, nothing breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using " in two different meanings. You shouldn't use them within your onload string definition. Try instead to define a function with your setInterval lines and load the function name in the onload attribute.

(or escape the double quotes of course!)

Answer (score 0):

You properly escaped the `"` in your php code, but you also need to make sure it is escaped in the HTML that gets parsed by the browser!

Use `&quot;`.

[This topic may be useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003345/html-onload-using-variables-as-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up `"` and `'` on various occasions in your code.

try something like this (also includes usage of functions, instead of strings in the `setInterval()` function and separating JavaScript from HTML markup):

```
<script>
function clockTimer( time, clock ) {
  setInterval( function(){ updateClock( time, clock ) }, 1000 );
}

function onLoader() {
  clockTimer("2012-10-31 13:14:01","clock0");
  clockTimer("2012-08-30 13:10:31","clock1");
  clockTimer("2012-08-30 10:16:46","clock2");
  clockTimer("2012-08-30 10:17:28","clock3");
  clockTimer("2012-09-07 10:17:47","clock4");
  clockTimer("2012-08-30 10:18:27","clock5");
  clockTimer("2012-08-29 10:18:41","clock6");
}

window.onload = onLoader;
<script>

<body>
...
```