# How pass an e.value directly to js function, without an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

I have a js function that receives an e.value as parameter from a text field element.

```
function myfunc(e){
   // here I use the e.value
}
```

How can I on onload invoke and pass a string as value to myfunc() directly without use an element?

This does not work:

```
<body onload="myfunc('my_value')">
```

Comment: `function myfunc(val){
   console.log(val)
}` - no need for e which is normally reserved for events

Comment: Better: `window.addEventListener("load",function() { myFunc("value") })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML onload - using variables as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003345/html-onload-using-variables-as-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you want to invoke that function, and in that function use the `e.value`?

In that case you should pass an object with a `value` property:

```js
function myfunc(e) {
  console.log(e.value);

  //do something with e.value
}
```

```html
<body onload="myfunc({ value: 'My value here' })"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function expects to receive an object with a `value` property.

If you pass it a string, then it will try to read the `value` property of that string and get `undefined`.

Either change the function to expect a plain string and not an object (or that tests to see if it is passed a string or an object), or change what you pass so it is an object with a `value` property.

Answer (score 0):

simply:

```
function myfunc(x){
   // x is your input
 }
```

`e` is reserved for events, while `this` refer to the target element